# Loess - y-coordinates not showing up correctly

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I am using the dataset `flu` from `astsa` package and it contains monthly measurement-values from 1968 to 1978.

Now I would like to have a sequence of the same range (12*11=132) which contains exactly these measuring time points, so that I will be able to plot a loess-curve with lines, like in the code below.

Unfortunately, the red loess curve is completely flat, even though it looks good if I plot it separately (with x=measurement_points).

The problem is definitely the time measurement points, I just can't use them properly as a index for lines(Predict Loess). How can I solve this properly with my dataset?

```
install.packages("astsa")
library(astsa)
data(flu)
tm <- seq(flu)
infpneum <- ts(flu,start=1968,freq=12)
res <- loess(infpneum ~ tm,span=0.1) 
pred <- predict(res)
measurement_points <- seq(as.Date("1968-01-01"),as.Date("1978-12-31"),by="months")
plot(infpneum)
lines(pred,type="l",col="red",x=measurement_points)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```r
plot (measurement_points, infpneum, type = "l")
lines(measurement_points, res$fitted, type="l", col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution is creating a timeseries object by imitating `infpneum` structure:

```r
library(astsa); data(flu)
tm <- seq(flu)
infpneum <- ts(flu,start=1968,freq=12)

str(infpneum) #just to see how it's structured 
 ## Time-Series [1:132] from 1968 to 1979: 0.811 0.446 0.342 0.277 0.248 ...

res <- loess(infpneum ~ tm,span=0.1)
pred <- ts(predict(res),start=1968,freq=12)

str(pred) #just to see how it's structured
 ## Time-Series [1:132] from 1968 to 1979: 0.706 0.54 0.41 0.314 0.248 ...

plot(infpneum)
lines(pred,type="l",col="red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>